# Large table table1 must appear as the leftmost table in a join query

Tags: inner-join, google-bigquery

this must be a simple question but i need some help.

When trying to join 2 tables in bigquery I get the message:  Large table tableName1 must appear as the leftmost table in a join query

If I invert the tables in join, i get the same error with the other table:  Large table tableName2  must appear as the leftmost table in a join query

I'm in a infinite loop. examples:

SELECT tableName1.col1 FROM tableName1 INNER JOIN  tableName2 ON tableName1.col1=tableName2.col1 ;

SELECT tableName1.col1 FROM tableName2 INNER JOIN  tableName1 ON tableName2.col1=tableName1.col1 ;

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, just found this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731412/joining-2-equally-sized-tables-in-google-bigquery?rq=1

Which is so disapointing... we have some HUGE data to join....

Comment: INNER JOIN EACH solves the problem

Comment: Look at the second answer there (2013) - use JOIN EACH :)

Comment: I just updated my answer to that old topic so hopefully this won't confuse people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try JOIN EACH, instead of JOIN:

Working example with real data:

```
SELECT a.Topic FROM [data-sensing:lab:io_sensor_data.moscone_io13] a
INNER JOIN EACH [data-sensing-lab:io_sensor_data.moscone_io13] b
ON a.timestamp=b.timestamp 
LIMIT 1000
```